# Vertically-aligning an image within a smaller container

Tags: html, css

Okay here's my issue. I have a block that is 348px wide, and on the right 144px, I want to center an image vertically. Easy, right? My issue is that I don't know the height of either the image or the block. How can I vertically center the image to go past the top of the container without making it a background image?

```
CSS
#block { width: 348px; position: relative; }
#content { width: 164px; padding: 20px; margin-right: 144px; }
#image { width: 144px; position: absolute; right: 0; }

MARKUP
<div id="block">
    <div id="image"><img url="imageurl" /></div>
    <div id="content">Some content goes here.</div>
</div>
```

I don't know how much that will help, but hopefully it does something.

Comment: You can do that with a css based solution, but the appropriated method depends on your HTML markup. Can't you provide the relevant HTML/CSS for your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's just a general question. This is a private client, and the content and design is confidential until release. I wish I could provide markup, as it would help a lot. I'll throw together some generic code though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A solution using only CSS**, based on your current HTML markup and as pointed out by your tags can be accomplished like this:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/8w7Gx/) example!

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="block">
    <div id="content">Some content goes here.</div>
    <div id="image">
        <img src="path_to_image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#block {
    width: 348px;
    display: table;         /* set the main wrapper to display as a table */
}
#content {
    width: 164px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#image {
    width: 144px;
    display: table-cell;    /* set the inner wrapper to display as a cell */
    vertical-align: middle; /* tell to vertically align the contents */
}
```

Was necessary to remove some css `position` declarations that conflict with the technic being used. But you can achieve exactly the same layout without them, thus allowing the CSS `vertical-align:middle` to work as expected.

---

**A jQuery solution** to your markup without removing any of your existent CSS declarations and achieving exactly the same goal:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/HNVGU/) example!

[image]

**jQuery**

Get to the `img` inside the `#image` and collect its height, divide it by two and apply a negative margin to it with the resulting value.

```
$(function() {
  var $target = $('#image').find('img');

  $target.css({
    "margin-top" : "-" + ($target.height()/2) + "px" // adjust the top margin
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#block {
    width: 348px;
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    width: 164px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-right: 144px;
}
#image {
    width: 144px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;              /* fit to the top */
    bottom: 0;           /* fit to the bottom */
    /*overflow:hidden;*/ /* optional if the img is bigger that this container */
}
#image img {
    position: absolute;  /* remove element from the document flow */
    top: 50%;            /* move it down by 50% of its parent height */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="block">
    <div id="image">
        <img src="path_to_image" />
    </div>
    <div id="content">Some content goes here.</div>
</div>
```

Your current markup is preserved and some extra css was added to make it work. Leaving the jQuery part as simple as possible!

Comment: And of course, this will not work with IE6 or IE7.  IE7 is still quite prevelent.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't quite achieve what I'm going for. What if the image is bigger than the other content of the container? I basically want an even overflow on both top and bottom. And I have padding within the block, so that's why it's absolutely positioned.

Comment: I wanted the image to break past the padding and to be on the edges of the right and top. And IE7 is a must-have-working.

Comment: @Zuul - Don't be ridiculous.  You're using w3schools statistics, which also show total IE usage at 18%, which is nowhere near realistic.  My own logs still show IE at > 70%.  w3schools has a MUCH higher share of tech savvy users who are web developers, thus they tend to use chrome and FF.  Real stats are hard to come by, but i'd rate IE7 still at 10%.

Comment: Regardless, IE7 is a browser that we're testing for, so it needs to be compatible :P doesn't really matter if it's 2.1 or 10%

Comment: It took a little bit of tweaking because of what sort of content I had, but it worked! Thanks for doing my math for me :)

Comment: My code worked in the most recent Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, and also in IE7,8, and 9. I wasn't able to test Safari, but as far as I can tell, everything works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely position the image inside the container or if that doesn't work in your case, you'll have to use javascript to get the height of the container and the height of the image and position the image that way.

To set it via CSS:

Set a style of "position:relative" on your container element. Then, set a style on your image to "position:absolute; top:50%;". You may also have to add a height to your container.

Comment: Setting an abs on top of 50% would just push it down 50% into the container, rather than making the center of the image the center of the block. Javascript is an alternative, but one that I'd rather not use. To bring the image up from the abs pos of 50% from the top, you'd have to set a negative margin for half the height of the image, which would be coupled with JS. I'm just curious if there are any CSS options.

Comment: If you don't know the height of the image or the height of the container, I don't see any other way to accomplish this other than dynamically setting the CSS via javascript.

Comment: I'll definitely keep JS as an option. Thanks.

Comment: That's 50% of the container, not the image :-/